# How to apply two @RunWith in spring boot starter test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4, parameterized-tests, junitparams

I am using spring boot starter test for writing JUnit test cases. I would love to use JunitParamrunner which facilitates passing files for parameterized test.Basically it reads data from file line by line and for every line invoke a test case. The issue is to use both I need to pass @RunWith with both SpringJUnit4ClassRunner as well as JUnitParamsRunner.
I am not able to figure out how to do that. Can any one provide some leads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SpringClassRule mentioned by @wjans if the best solution, but if your Spring version is less than 4.2 (the latest spring-boot-starter-test depends on spring version 4.1.7), you can initialize the context in test constructor:

```
@ContextConfiguration(<your context location>)
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ParameterizedTestWithSpring {

    private TestContextManager testContextManager;

    public ParametrizedTestWithSpring() throws Exception {
        this.testContextManager = new TestContextManager(getClass());
        this.testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);
    }

    // your test methods
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to achieve your spring integration by using the [SpringClassRule](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/rules/SpringClassRule.html) instead of the `@RunWith` annotation.